# I'm submitting the form through ajax using jquery serialization function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
var values = $('#form_field').serialize();
dataS = "val="+values;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: dataS,
    cache: false, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) 
    { },
});
```

But the form has an (`<input type="file">` field) how do I pass the file into the form using this ajax serialization method. When I print `$_FILES` doesn't getting any output.

Comment: Google - `ajax file upload`

Comment: file won't post with ajax in normal way, i would recommend  jquery image uploader plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can't past the $_FILES variable when using ajax. I can assure you that. Thanks.

Comment: What about XHR2's FormData API?

Comment: It's not compatible with all browser.

Comment: He's using PHP as well.

Comment: If your excuse is "not supported by all browsers", you may as well go back and code in HTML1 for Mosaic.

Comment: No one use Mosaic at this time.

Comment: That's the point. If you look at [XHR2 support table](http://caniuse.com/xhr2), only IE<10 does not support it (which is about 3~7% browser market share, but that varies greatly depending on your actual target audience). Even if you need to support those pesky ancient IE, file upload is still doable through iframe hackery anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax does not support file uploads, you should use iframe instead.
you can check further detail [here](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Posting via Ajax file upload isn't straight forward.  First, it isn't directly doable using XHR1.

There are two main ways to do the uploads, using a frame and using the `XHR2` spec and the `FormData` object.  This is the method I would recommend.

The easiest way  to do this is then to perform two uploads. I'm going to borrow some code here, from [GitHub user optikalefx](https://gist.github.com/optikalefx) to show you how to do it using jQuery:

```
// Ajax File upload with jQuery and XHR2
// Sean Clark http://square-bracket.com
// xhr2 file upload
    // data is optional
    $.fn.upload = function(remote,data,successFn,progressFn) {
        // if we dont have post data, move it along
        if(typeof data != "object") {
            progressFn = successFn;
            successFn = data;
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            if($(this)[0].files[0]) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);

                // if we have post data too
                if(typeof data == "object") {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        formData.append(i,data[i]);
                    }
                }

                // do the ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: remote,
                    type: 'POST',
                    xhr: function() {
                        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if(myXhr.upload && progressFn){
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(prog) {
                                var value = ~~((prog.loaded / prog.total) * 100);

                                // if we passed a progress function
                                if(progressFn && typeof progressFn == "function") {
                                    progressFn(prog,value);

                                // if we passed a progress element
                                } else if (progressFn) {
                                    $(progressFn).val(value);
                                }
                            }, false);
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    },
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    complete : function(res) {
                        var json;
                        try {
                            json = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                        } catch(e) {
                            json = res.responseText;
                        }
                        if(successFn) successFn(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

I should also note that browser support for this is a little more limited, despite XHR2 being around for 2 years now:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData  contains more information as well as a Browser compatibility chart.